# Convertir jQuery a Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy haciendo una funcion para que no coincidan en el mismo espacio dos div.
He cogido el codigo, que funciona, de otra pagina que utiliza jQuery.
Queria pasarlo a Javascript, pero la primera parte me falla.
Gracias!

```
  $(window).on('resize scroll', function () {
            if ($('#sidebar').isInViewport()) {
                $('#divFlotante').hide(250);
            } else {
                $('#divFlotante').show(250);
            }
        });
```

**Esto es con jQuery**

**Lo intento cambiar a Javascript** asi:

```
 window.on('resize scroll', function () {
    if (document.getElementById('sidebar').isInViewport()) {
        document.getElementById('divFlotante').hide(250);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('divFlotante').show(250);
    }
});
```

Lo que no se cambiar es el window.on

Comment: `window.addEventListener('resize', function() { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos opciones:

Opción 1

```
window.onresize = function(ev) {
    ....
}
```

Opción 2

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(ev) {

})
```

con respecto al isInViewPort te dejo un vínculo de como se podría hacer quizás te sirva

[JavaScript isInViewPort](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/dom/css/check-if-an-element-is-visible-in-the-viewport/)

ahora como quieres comprobar por dos funciones siempre puedes crear la función fuera y hacer lo siguiente

```
function checkResizeScroll(event) {

}
// Opción 1
window.onresize = checkResizeScroll;
window.onscroll = checkResizeScroll;
// Opción 2
window.addEventListener('resize', checkResizeScroll)
window.addEventListener('scroll', checkResizeScroll)
```